# Android emulator OpenGL far plane distance

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I'm trying to render a simple square in OpenGl on Android. The same code behaves correctly on real devices, but on the emulator the square is deformed. This only happens when I use high zFar value (in this example it's zNear = 80000, zFar = 80100) and does not depend on distance between zNear and zFar. Depth test is disabled, so I don't think it has anything to do with the depth buffer.

This is how it looks on a real device:

[image: http://imgur.com/9246P]

And this is how it looks on an emulator.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/L0IKv.png]

When the square is rotating the deformations become more visible, and at some point the square disappears and then reappears again.

I know that the emulator uses a different implementation of OpenGl, maybe it's a bug?
Does anybody know why it's behaving like this?

```
public class SquareTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GLSurfaceView glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView.setRenderer(new SquareRenderer());

        setContentView(glView);
    }

    public class SquareRenderer implements Renderer {
        private final float[] verts = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f };
        private final int nrOfVerts = verts.length / 3;
        private FloatBuffer vertBuf;

        private float rotation;

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) { 
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

            gl.glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(verts.length * Float.SIZE / 8);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertBuf = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
            vertBuf.put(verts);
            vertBuf.position(0);
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 90, (float) width / height, 80000, 80100);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 80050, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
            gl.glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);
            gl.glScalef(80000, 80000, 1);

            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuf);
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, nrOfVerts);

            rotation ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have, even a cheap device, I would suggest to test on actual decives only. You may experience OpenGL caveats not existing in the emulator. The OpenGL specifications are quite exact but also comprehensive, so they are nowhere implemented completely. I think that could be a numeric precision problem, which could differ from platform to platform. If the application is for public release you have to test on 'some' devices either.

Comment: I have tested this on wide range of devices and it works as expected on all of them. I wish I could drop the emulator support, but since this is a library project users might expect to be able to run it on their emulators.

Comment: So the emulator is just another one device to please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the effect from your code, and the problem goes away if you divide all of those 80000-ish numbers by 10. I suspect that the emulator's OpenGL implementation is using fixed-point arithmetic internally, which would cause it to struggle with numbers that big. If it uses the glFixed format (S15.16), it will not be able to handle numbers greater than 32768.

Comment: Yes I suspected that as well, deformations start showing up around that range. It doesn't make much sense though, why strip out / replace  the floating point math used in OpenglES just for the emulator?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES) mentions the common lite profile for OpenGL ES, which only supports fixed point. Maybe the emulator only implements that profile. (I'm struggling to find any confirmation for that, though.)